# Retrieve window position of maximized minimized window

Tags: windows, winapi

Consider this situation:

- on a multi-monitor system,
- an application was maximized, then minimized,
- in my application I have the HWND of the main window of above application

Now, how can I determine which monitor the window will show on when restored from minimized state? GetWindowRect and GetWindowInfo results in negative values, and apparently the same for all monitors. GetWindowPlacement gives good values in rcNormalPosition, but these are the coordinates the application returns to when un-maximized, which could be partly or wholly on another monitor.

Comment: I've never tried this, but doesn't `WINDOWPLACEMENT.ptMaxPosition` give you the answer?

Comment: Nope, those hold the same negative values I get from GetWindowRect and GetWindowInfo

Comment: Negative values doesn't mean that they're the *wrong* values. The virtual desktop contains points with negative coordinate values.

Comment: If the negative values were different if the application is on either monitor, I would try to make sense of them. Since they're the same on both monitors, I don't think I could find what I'm searching there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `MonitorFromRect` function with `rcNormalPosition` and `MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST` flag. After that - call `GetMonitorInfo` to determine working monitor area.

Comment: There's still a chance rcNormalPosition (the coordinates the window takes when un-minimizing) are on another monitor than the one it's currently maximized to, but by default it should have gotten maximized to the monitor the most of the window was on, so I'll accept this answer.